# Hosting a FEMA floodmap to a subset of the layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Going to try this one more time as I think the last time I posted this I was unclear.

I have this [map here](http://bl.ocks.org/dyavrom/119a891d0f1e804aa262596d569acff3), that is a combination of some ArcGIS analysis and written in Mapbox GL JS. Basically, it is looking at whether some stores fall in a high risk flood zone via FEMA data.

This issue is as follows: the current flood layer I have displayed (the pink layer) is of ALL the floodzones in the US, but I only need a subset of this data which displays only high-risk floodzones. This data exists as a value field, and generally looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eraWZ.jpg)

The way I ran the analysis was to use a local file in ArcGIS (I was able to download the FEMA data from data.gov). I am open to converting and hosting the file online if needed, but would rather subset the data server side and load it into the map.

I know that there are options for WFS and WMS, but I cannot seem to make them work.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do?

Code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title></title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
    <style>
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
        .marker {
          background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/48/map-marker-icon.png');
          background-size: cover;
          width: 12px;
          height: 12px;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 0px;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup {
          max-width: 200px;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup-content {
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        .map-overlay {
            font:12px 'Inconsolata';
            color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
            position: absolute;
            width: 25%;
            height: 0%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: -10px;
            padding: 7px;
        }

        .map-overlay .map-overlay-inner {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
            border-radius: 4px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .map-overlay label {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 10px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 6px;
            color: black;
        }

        .map-overlay input {
            background-color: transparent;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            bottom: 13px;
            cursor: ew-resize;
        }
      </style>

<div id='map'></div>
<div id='menu'>
</div>

<div class='map-overlay top'>
<div class='map-overlay-inner'>
    <label>Layer opacity: <span id='slider-value'>100%</span></label>
    <input id='slider' type='range' min='0' max='100' step='0' value='100' />
</div>
</div>


<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoiZHlhdnJvbSIsImEiOiJjamVoNDc0MGowYjBlMndvNjRkMjEwenExIn0.uTE8zI8EL    LNs1rIT2_Od2A';

//load map
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
    center: [-96, 37.8],
    zoom: 3.5,
    attributionControl:false
  });

  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var sliderValue = document.getElementById('slider-value');

//add second layer of data
    map.on('load', function() {
      var layers = map.getStyle().layers;
// Find the index of the first symbol layer in the map style
  var firstSymbolId;
      for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
          if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
              firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
              break;
          }
      }

  //add the FEMA WMS layer
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'wms',
        'type': 'raster',
        'source': {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': [
          'https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/export?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&bboxSR=EPSG%3A3857&layers=28&layerDefs=&size=256%2c256&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=true&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&f=image'
        ],firstSymbolId}}
      );
      });

      slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      // Adjust the layers opacity. layer here is arbitrary - this could
      // be another layer name found in your style or a custom layer
      // added on the fly using `addSource`.
      map.setPaintProperty('wms', 'raster-opacity', parseInt(e.target.value, 10) / 100);

      // Value indicator
      sliderValue.textContent = e.target.value + '%';
      });


  // input data
          var geojson = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "name": "XYCA_GIS_selection",
            "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
            "features": [
            { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "1", "Region": 4, "Name": "Test 1", "Lat": 30.669177, "Long": -89.040369, "acreage": 0, "Street_Num": 1101.0, "Street_1": "Test", "Street_2": null, "City": "Test", "State": "PA", "Address_zi": "36609", "Extract_Fl": "X", "Federal_Fa": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -88.040369, 30.669177 ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "2", "Region": 4, "Name": "Test 2", "Lat": 34.701014, "Long": -82.362305, "acreage": 10, "Street_Num": 201.0, "Street_1": "Test", "Street_2": null, "City": "Test", "State": "MA", "Address_zi": "35999", "Extract_Fl": "X", "Federal_Fa": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -86.362305, 34.701014 ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "3", "Region": 4, "Name": "Test3", "Lat": 34.76722, "Long": -87.940198, "acreage": 7.0, "Street_Num": 1000.0, "Street_1": "Test", "Street_2": null, "City": "Test", "State": "AL", "Address_zi": "35699", "Extract_Fl": "X", "Federal_Fa": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -85.940198, 34.76722 ] } },

            ]
            }



  // add markers to map
  geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);

  //add popups
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.Name + '</h3><h5>'
    + marker.properties.Address + " "
    + marker.properties.City + ", "
    + marker.properties.State + '</h5>'))
    .addTo(map);
  });

  // Add Geocoder
  map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  }), 'top-right');

  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl(), 'bottom-right');
  // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'bottom-right');

  // Add geolocate control to the map.
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
      positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
      },
      trackUserLocation: true
  }), 'bottom-right');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't how GIS SE works. Instead of reposting the question, rewritten, you're supposed to edit the closed question to rehabilitate it.

Comment: Please edit your previous question so that it may be reviewed for re-opening rather than re-asking the same albeit improved question as a new question.